# Chrome extension's popup.html not displaying after Chrome 66.0 update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm stumped. My Chrome extension is mainly based on the popup.html.

It was working fine on Chrome 65.x . I received a bug report from users on Chrome 66.0 saying that the extension would not show correctly.

I updated Chrome to 66.0 and I could reproduce the bug. The popup.html quickly flashes and gets cropped into a tiny little white square as if it is empty.

What could be the issue?

Manifest:

```
{

  "description": "...",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.5.0",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [
       "tabs",
       "cookies",
       "<all_urls>"
   ],
  "browser_action": {
    "browser_style": true,
    "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
  }

}
```

popup.html contains a local copy of KnockoutJS. When removing all Javascript it loads correctly. However there have been no changes in the JS code since Chrome 65 where it was working correctly.

Comment: Show your manifest.json and minimal relative code?

Comment: Right-click on the extension's icon, select "Inspect pop-up" and look for errors in the Console. Report here any relevant messages so we can provide further assistance

Comment: No errors in console, popup occasionally shows correctly when inspecting though

Comment: Might be a bug in Chrome 66. See if it's fixed in Chrome Canary, otherwise report on https://crbug.com if it's not reported already.

Comment: I've filed a bug here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=838838

Comment: If I click it often enough, it sometimes opens correctly, further reinforcing the probability that it's a Chrome bug.

Comment: It appears its due to: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=428044

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with Chrome 66: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=428044

Temporary workaround was to re-style the body after load to force a repaint with a setTimeout.

```
    // This height calculation is excessive due to padding, but it's not worth
    // the extra coding effort to get it pixel-perfect (e.g. getComputedStyle).
    const height = document.body.clientHeight;
    // Set it slightly bigger immediately so hopefully this will lead to less
    // flashing/refreshing.  It's not clear whether this always worksaround the
    // bug though :(.
    document.body.style.height = `${height + 1}px`;
    // Schedule an update in case the window is still too small.  Hopefully
    // this will catch the rest.  If we already workedaround it, we'll only
    // make the window slightly bigger so the user won't notice.
    setTimeout(() => document.body.style.height = `${height + 2}px`, 100);
    setTimeout(() => document.body.style.height = ``, 110)
```